# Initialize method throwing runtime exception when button clicked

Tags: java, javafx, initialization

I have a project in JavaFX in which it tracks student's volunteer records. I am having problems with the initialize method. I called a Combobox to fill an observable ArrayList when it initializes. When it initializes, no errors are thrown, but when I click a button, I get this weird error message:

```
11
System log: Launched
11
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/FBLA2020CompetitionCode/out/production/FBLA2020CompetitionCode/sample/addStudent.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample.controllerHome.addStudentPopup(controllerHome.java:115)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.controllerHome.initialize(controllerHome.java:68)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 63 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

here is the controller class

```
    package sample;

    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.*;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
    import javafx.stage.Modality;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class controllerHome implements Initializable {
        //csv class
        csvReader reader;
        //Global Screen, keeps track of the screens
        Scene scene;
        Stage window;

        //global components needed
        @FXML private ComboBox<String> chooseStudent;

        //hashmap and the student
        HashMap studentMap = new HashMap();
        ArrayList<volunteer> volunteerHours;

        ObservableList<String> allNames = csvReader.getName();


        //Table DATA




        // add student components
        @FXML private TextField addStudentTextBox;
        @FXML private Button okButtonAS;
        @FXML private Button cancelAS;
        @FXML private Label errorAS;
        @FXML private TextField gradeTextBoxAS;

        //Ok button for the instructions
        @FXML private Button okButton;

        //Edit box buttons/controls
        @FXML private Button okButtonEdit;


        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
            chooseStudent.setItems(allNames);
        }

        public void loadHome(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            Parent view2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HOME.fxml"));
            scene= new Scene(view2);
            window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
            System.out.println("System log: Loaded home");
        }


        public void print(ActionEvent actionEvent)  throws IOException{



        }

        public void loadInstructions(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
            Parent view2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("instructions.fxml"));
            window = new Stage();
            scene = new Scene(view2);
            window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            window.setTitle("Instructions");
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
            System.out.println("System log: Loaded instructions");

        }

        public void editPopup(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
            Parent view = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("editBox.fxml"));
            window = new Stage();
            scene = new Scene(view);
            window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            window.setTitle("Edit");
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
            System.out.println("System log: Loaded edit");
        }


        public void searchStudent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        }

        public void addStudentPopup(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
            Parent view = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addStudent.fxml"));
            window = new Stage();
            scene = new Scene(view);
            window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            window.setTitle("Add Student");
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
        }

        public void deleteStudentPopup(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
            Parent view = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("deleteStudent.fxml"));
            Stage window = new Stage();
            scene = new Scene(view);
            window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            window.setTitle("Delete Student");
            window.setScene(scene);
            window.show();
        }

        public void loadStudent(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
            Parent view2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("student.fxml"));
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(view2);
            Stage window = (Stage)((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            window.setScene(scene2);
            window.show();
        }



        public boolean stringContainsNumber( String s )
        {
            return Pattern.compile( "[0-9]" ).matcher( s ).find();
        }




        //all actions for addStudentButtons
        public void addStudentComponents(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException{
            if(actionEvent.getSource() == okButtonAS) {
                System.out.println("inside ok button");
                if (!addStudentTextBox.getText().equals("") && !gradeTextBoxAS.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("passed the null checker");

                    boolean x = false;

                    try {

                        Integer.parseInt(gradeTextBoxAS.getText());
                        x = true;


                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        x = false;
                    }

                    if(x == true && (Integer.parseInt(gradeTextBoxAS.getText()) > 12 || Integer.parseInt(gradeTextBoxAS.getText()) < 6)){
                        System.out.println("did not pass the grade checker");
                        errorAS.setText("ERROR: You entered a grade < 6 or > 12 ");
                        errorAS.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("passed grade checker");
                        if(stringContainsNumber(addStudentTextBox.getText()) || x == false){
                            System.out.println("Found compatibility error");
                            errorAS.setVisible(true);
                            errorAS.setText("ERROR: compatibility error!");
                        }
                        else{
                            csvReader.addStudentCSV(addStudentTextBox.getText(),Integer.parseInt(gradeTextBoxAS.getText()),getRandomNumberInRange(11111111,99999999));
                            allNames.add(addStudentTextBox.getText());
                        }
                    }


                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("didnt pass null checker");
                    errorAS.setVisible(true);
                    errorAS.setText("text fields are null");

                }
            }
            if(actionEvent.getSource() == cancelAS){
                Stage window = (Stage)((Node)actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                window.close();

            }


        }
        private static int getRandomNumberInRange(int min, int max) {

            if (min >= max) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        }



        public void editPopupComponents(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to HOME.FXML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
    <?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

    <AnchorPane fx:id="homePane" style="-fx-background-color: #02030A;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controllerHome">
        <children>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" style="-fx-background-color: #3282B8#3282B8;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <children>
                    <ImageView fitHeight="210.0" fitWidth="227.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                        <image>
                            <Image url="@../images/Flag-color.png" />
                        </image>
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="10.0" top="50.0" />
                        </VBox.margin></ImageView>
                    <Label text="FBLA Volunteer Portal" textFill="WHITE">
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets bottom="20.0" />
                        </VBox.margin>
                        <font>
                            <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
                        </font>
                    </Label>
                    <Button fx:id="homeButton" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="22.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadHome" prefHeight="210.0" prefWidth="256.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3282B8#3282B8;" text="Home" textFill="WHITE">
                        <graphic>
                            <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                <image>
                                    <Image url="@../images/icons8_Home_32px.png" />
                                </image>
                            </ImageView>
                        </graphic>
                        <opaqueInsets>
                            <Insets />
                        </opaqueInsets>
                        <VBox.margin>
                            <Insets />
                        </VBox.margin>
                        <padding>
                            <Insets left="50.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </Button>
                <Button fx:id="printButton" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="22.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#print" prefHeight="210.0" prefWidth="256.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3282B8#3282B8;" text="Print" textFill="WHITE">
                   <graphic>
                      <ImageView fitHeight="26.0" fitWidth="28.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                         <image>
                            <Image url="@../images/icons8_Open_Envelope_32px.png" />
                         </image>
                      </ImageView>
                   </graphic>
                   <padding>
                      <Insets left="50.0" />
                   </padding>
                </Button>
                </children>
            </VBox>
            <StackPane layoutX="258.0" style="-fx-background-color: #02030A;">
                <children>
                    <Pane fx:id="exit" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="685.0" prefWidth="790.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1b262c#1b262c;">
                        <children>
                            <TextField fx:id="searchStudent" layoutX="590.0" layoutY="47.0" onAction="#searchStudent" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="183.0" promptText="Search Students" style="-fx-background-color: #1b262c#1b262c; -fx-border-color: #B7C3D7; -fx-border-radius: 2em;" />
                            <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="404.0" text="FBLA/PBL Volunteer Tracker " textFill="#e7e5e5">
                                <font>
                                    <Font size="24.0" />
                                </font>
                            </Label>
                            <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="93.0" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="746.0" spacing="50.0">
                                <children>
                                    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                                        <children>
                                            <Label fx:id="totalHours" text="N/A" textFill="#2a73ff">
                                                <font>
                                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="26.0" />
                                                </font>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="81.0" text="   Total Hours" textFill="#e7e5e5" />
                                        </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                                        <children>
                                            <Label fx:id="monthlyHours" text="N/A" textFill="#26bfbc">
                                                <font>
                                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="26.0" />
                                                </font>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label text="Monthly Hours" textFill="#e7e5e5" />
                                        </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                                        <children>
                                            <Label fx:id="schoolYearHours" text="N/A" textFill="#fa5f7e">
                                                <font>
                                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="26.0" />
                                                </font>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="School Year Hours" textFill="#e7e5e5" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                                        </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                    <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                                        <children>
                                            <Label fx:id="studentCount" text="N/A" textFill="#de0000">
                                                <font>
                                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="26.0" />
                                                </font>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Label prefWidth="100.0" text="    # of Students" textFill="#e7e5e5" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                                        </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                </children>
                            </HBox>
                            <ScrollPane layoutX="22.0" layoutY="283.0" prefHeight="385.0" prefWidth="746.0">
                                <content>
                                    <VBox prefHeight="385.0" prefWidth="744.0" spacing="5.0" style="-fx-background-color: #02030A;">
                                        <padding>
                                            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                                        </padding>
                               <children>
                                  <TableView fx:id="tableView" prefHeight="392.0" prefWidth="734.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1b262c#1b262c #1b262c#1b262c;">
                                    <columns>
                                      <TableColumn fx:id="Name" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                                      <TableColumn fx:id="Grade" prefWidth="75.0" text="Grade" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="ID" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="totalHours" prefWidth="75.0" text="totalHours" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="Awards" prefWidth="75.0" text="Awards" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="hours" prefWidth="75.0" text="Hours" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="program" prefWidth="75.0" text="Program" />
                                        <TableColumn fx:id="date" prefWidth="75.0" text="Date" />
                                    </columns>
                                     <columnResizePolicy>
                                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                     </columnResizePolicy>
                                  </TableView>
                               </children>
                                    </VBox>
                                </content>
                            </ScrollPane>
                            <ImageView fitHeight="17.0" fitWidth="16.0" layoutX="749.0" layoutY="53.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                <image>
                                    <Image url="@../images/icons8_Search_52px.png" />
                                </image>
                            </ImageView>
                      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="22.0" layoutY="213.0" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="746.0" spacing="50.0">
                         <children>
                            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Button fx:id="instructionButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadInstructions" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="185.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2a73ff#2a73ff;" text="Instructions" textFill="WHITE" />
                                  <Label textFill="#e7e5e5" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Button fx:id="editButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#editPopup" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="165.0" style="-fx-background-color: #26bfbc#26bfbc;" text="Edit" textFill="WHITE" />
                                  <Label prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="71.0" textFill="#e7e5e5" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Button fx:id="addStudentButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addStudentPopup" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="290.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fa5f7e#fa5f7e;" text="Add Student" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                                  <Label prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="97.0" textFill="#e7e5e5" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="290.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fa5f7e#fa5f7e;" text="Add Hours" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="187.0">
                               <children>
                                  <Button fx:id="deleteStudentButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteStudentPopup" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="196.0" style="-fx-background-color: #de0000#de0000;" text="Delete Student" textFill="WHITE" />
                                  <Label prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="98.0" textFill="#e7e5e5" textOverrun="CLIP" />
                                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="196.0" style="-fx-background-color: #de0000#de0000;" text="Delete Hours" textFill="WHITE" />
                               </children>
                            </VBox>
                         </children>
                      </HBox>
                      <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="47.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="404.0" text="Summary/Overview" textFill="#9e9a9a">
                         <font>
                            <Font size="18.0" />
                         </font>
                      </Label>
                      <ComboBox fx:id="chooseStudent" layoutX="430.0" layoutY="48.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
                        </children>
                    </Pane>
                </children>
            </StackPane>
        </children>
        <effect>
            <DropShadow color="#1b1eeb" />
        </effect>
    </AnchorPane>
```

I think there is an error with the buttons itself in my controller class, its either I need to add try and catches or something is going on with the controller class. My code is a bit messy but I hope its readable, thanks!

Comment: Are you using the same class for two different controllers for different FXML files?

Comment: i have only one controller class with multiple fxml files but I have 3 other classes for reading csv, student class and volunteer class

Comment: Every time you load a fxml a new controller instance is created. This means that only those fxmls that contain a element with `fx:id="chooseStudent"` won't be problematic...

Comment: so do I have to hard code the controller instance for each FXML document?

Comment: Yes, use a different controller class for each FXML.

Comment: then how do I link them with the HomeController is all of them will have different controllers?

Comment: it says it cannot find the FXML files if assign it to different controllers

Comment: Not finding the FXML files is a different problem entirely; it likely just means the resource path is wrong. 
You can share data between controllers using any of the techniques in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310

Comment: then what is the problem, im back to square one